# PHP how to show all decimal places?

Tags: php, decimal, number-formatting

this might be a stupid question but I have searched again and again without finding any results.

So, what I want is to show all the decimal places of a number without knowing how many decimal places it will have. Take a look at this small code:

```
$arrayTest = array(0.123456789, 0.0123456789);

foreach($arrayTest as $output){
    $newNumber = $output/1000;
    echo $newNumber;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

It gives this output:

```
0.000123456789
1.23456789E-5
```

Now, I tried using 'number_format', but I don't think that is a good solution. It determines an exact amount of decimal places, and I do not know the amount of decimal places for every number. Take a look at the below code:

```
$arrayTest = array(0.123456789, 0.0123456789);

foreach($arrayTest as $output){
    $newNumber = $output/1000;
    echo number_format($newNumber,13);
    echo "<br>";
}
```

It gives this output:

```
0.0001234567890
0.0000123456789
```

Now, as you can see there is an excess 0 in the first number, because number_format forces it to have 13 decimal places.

I would really love some guidance on how to get around this problem. Is there a setting in PHP.ini which determines the amount of decimals? 
Thank you very much in advance!
(and feel free to ask if you have any further questions)

Comment: You do realize, I hope, that a decimal representation of a floating point number is almost always approximate?

Answer (score 3):

It is "impossible" to answer this question properly - because a binary float representation of a decimal number is approximate: ["What every computer scientist should know about floating point"](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~dwharder/NumericalAnalysis/02Numerics/Double/paper.pdf)

The closest you can come is write yourself a routine that looks at a decimal representation of a number, and compares it to the "exact" value; once the difference becomes "small enough for your purpose", you stop adding more digits.

This routine could then return the "correct number of digits" as a string.

Example:

```
<?php
$a = 1.234567890;
$b = 0.123456789;
echo returnString($a)."\n";
echo returnString($b)."\n";

function returnString($a) {
// return the value $a as a string
// with enough digits to be "accurate" - that is, the value returned
// matches the value given to 1E-10
// there is a limit of 10 digits to cope with unexpected inputs
// and prevent an infinite loop

  $conv_a = 0;
  $digits=0;

  while(abs($a - $conv_a) > 1e-10) {
    $digits = $digits + 1;
    $conv_a = 0 + number_format($a, $digits);
    if($digits > 10) $conv_a = $a;
  }

  return $conv_a;

}

?>
```

Which produces

```
1.23456789
0.123456789
```

In the above code I arbitrarily assumed that being right to within 1E-10 was good enough. Obviously you can change this condition to whatever is appropriate for the numbers you encounter - and you could even make it an optional argument of your function.

Play with it - ask questions if this is not clear.